# Shared and replication filesystem support POSIX

Tags: glusterfs, ceph

I'm looking for opensource solution that support my use case. I have now 4 node on my cluster network and i need this.

1. Store file system (huge list)
2. Replication my file save on one node and replicate to another one.
3. Shareding my files into 2 parts. (1 cluster, 2 replication, 2 shareding)
4. I can add node to my network ( 2 new nodes and my size of sharding will be grow) **important one**
5. It's so good to hear i can use cross data center replication for put geodns for client to access faster.
6. Also support POSIX

Simply as this

[image: Shared and replication filesystem]

I need to know any popular DFS support my use case or i must do it as application layer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're describing an exact use case for GlusterFS. Gluster will support file sharding, as well as replication and distribution (this policy is applied per-volume, not per-cluster). It also has an API that can be used to allow applications to natively access volumes, called `libgfapi`.

`libfgapi` is used commonly by libvirt / KVM to access GlusterFS volumes without having to use FUSE. If you want your application to connect directly, it's a very usable API. Otherwise, you would have to use FUSE on the client side to access Gluster volume data.